# id is not defined (sails.socket.emit)

Tags: node.js, sockets, undefined, sails.js

I'm simply trying to use sails.socket.emit() to send a message and I get this:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 Error (SAILS:HOOK:SOCKETS:USAGE):: `sails.sockets.get()` cannot lookup socket w/o an id (got: `undefined`)
```

The code in the controller:

```
sayHiToFriend: function(req, res) {
    var friendId = req.param('id');
    sails.sockets.emit(friendId, 'privateMessage', {from: req.session.userId, msg: 'Hi!'});
    res.json({
      message: 'Message sent!'
    });
}
```

And client side:

```
io.socket.get('/user/sayHiToFriend', function serverSays(err,users){

  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);*/
        if (err)
            console.log(err)

        console.log(JSON.stringify(users));

});
```

Do I have to pass the id as data to io.socket.get ? If so how?
edit: solution:

```
 sails.sockets.emit(sails.sockets.id(req.socket), 'welcome', {custom: 'data here'});
```

Comment: You'll have to provide your code.

Comment: Modified my original post. The original issue was some dumb syntax issue.. However now I get this one

Comment: Well, looks like something is undefined, so its either friendId or req.session.userId

Comment: Sorry I edited again, so you didn't see the relevant portion of the code I think. Seems like I can pass data to io.socket.get. This can remove the error but I get others. I don't know how to properly pass the socket Id...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It seems like Sails.js has some internal problems or something else we cannot control...in my case few hours ago all worked fine and now it gives that error. I solved it simply compacting the array of the IDs with lodash:

```
User.findOne({'id': req.body.id}, function(error, user) {
            var subscribers = _.compact(User.subscribers(user));
            sails.sockets.emit(subscribers, "notification", {msg: req.body.msg});
});
```

and now everything works fine! Hope it helps!